# Text messages no longer associated with contact

Tags: contacts, sms

My neighbour has a Nokia Lumia 520 and accidentally linked an existing contact ("Person A") with a new contact that he created ("Person B").

This has had some side-effect where Windows Phone seemed to get confused about text messages associated with Person A (the original contact). If he goes into the text message app, then it shows Person A's text messages under the name of Person B. If he goes into Person A's profile and selects the "Text" option, then nothing shows up at all.

To try and solve this, we deleted the "Person B" contact, and the text message app now shows the correct name on the existing message threads. However, when going via the profile, it still shows up as there being no messages.

Does anyone know how to fix up the contacts so that the existing text messages are correctly associated with the original contact again?

Comment: Can he try a call too? Because I'm having similar problem with calling.

Comment: That sounds very strange indeed,
I would guess that that is a software bug. what i would recommend is contacting Microsoft support or Nokia Care, and see if they can help you.

Comment: Just fixed in my case. I had phone number with its international format so I changed to the number plus area code and it fixed it.

Comment: Do you have international assist turned on?

Comment: @VitorCanova: Thanks for the suggestion - we tried that but no joy. Going to try just deleting the contact completely from both the phone and from the synchronized Outlook contacts, then re-adding it from the phone and see what happens.

Comment: You sure you don't have more than one contact with same number? Have you tried change the number using all combination with area code and country code?

Comment: Where are the contacts saved in his Microsoft Account?

Comment: Bug still isn't fixed as I've just experienced this exact same behaviour on a phone running the latest Dev preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your contacts are synced from an account (google or Live), the only way to solve this as of now is by choosing not to sync contacts `settings->email+account-> untick contact synching`, then sync your account and then tick the contact synching and resync again. This way will clear all bad cache and enforce linking correct contacts to SMS. The problem is, you will lose all the linking of contacts you have done earlier.

Comment: Thanks HaLaBi, this sounds good. I haven't had a chance to verify it yet, but will come back and let you know if it solved the problem.