# Contact profiles linked by mistake

Tags: sms, people-hub, linked-accounts, people

A strange thing has happened on my Nokia Lumia 520. Two of the contacts on my people list had got linked by mistake. I have now unlinked them but strangely messages received from contact x are now showing under contact y. New messages/calls from both contacts are however showing correctly. I tried deleting the two contacts and adding the numbers again but the problem persists. HELP!

Comment: Please follow [this](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/text-messages-no-longer-associated-with-contact)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with Windows Phone. Try deleting both contacts, and then re-adding them. I had the same issue once, and it fixed it for me.

Please make sure to search through current questions before asking your own. Here is a [similar thread](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/text-messages-no-longer-associated-with-contact).